# os.path.exists Returns False w/ Escaped Paths Including Spaces

Tags: python, macos, os.path

I've run across a seemingly strange issue in Python and all the Googling in the world hasn't helped. I'm trying to simply check whether or not a path exists in Python. The code below returns expected results with paths that do not have spaces, but as soon as there's a folder with a space, it no longer works.

```
import os

temp = "~/Documents/Example File Path/"
temp = temp.strip('\n')
tempexpanded = os.path.expanduser(temp)
tempesc = tempexpanded.replace(" ", "\\ ")
if not os.path.exists(tempesc):
    print "Path does not exist"
else:
    print "Path exists"
```

For some reason, this results in printing "Path does not exist", even though the following works if I type it into the terminal:

```
cd /Users/jmoore/Documents/Example\ File\ Path/
```

When I breakpoint my code, tempesc has a value of:

> /Users/jmoore/Documents/Example\\ File\\ Path/

Given that, I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you need to escape the spaced? Try not escaping them.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that the operation of os.path.exists() is different than that of os.system(). The former wants unescaped strings, but commands done through os.system() require the escape.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't escape the spaces:

```
In [6]: temp = "~/Documents/Example File Path/"

In [7]: tempexpanded = os.path.expanduser(temp)

In [8]: os.path.exists(tempexpanded)
Out[8]: True
```

The following shell command will fail:

```
cd ~/Documents/Example File Path/
```

The above has three strings: `cd`,  `~/Documents/Example`,  `File`, and `Path/`.  The `cd` command, however, wants only one argument.

The following will work even though the spaces are not escaped:

```
tempexpanded=~/'Documents/Example File Path/'
cd "$tempexpanded"
```

The above works because the spaces are part of one string.  The same is true in your python code: the spaces are in one string variable.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Now that you pointed out exactly why, it seems obvious. Lol I wish I'd realized it a bit sooner.